# Is there a way to create a logic condition in packer provisioner?

Tags: json, packer

I am trying to add a condition so my volume_size: can get two different values depending on what is passed in "-var role="

I've tried something like this :

```
"volume_size": [{
     "Fn::If" : [
       ".ami_id_bar",
       {"foo" : "50"},
       {"foo" : "20"}
     ]
    }],
```

.ami_id_bar is a :

```
"environment_vars": [
          "ami_id_bar={{user `role`}}"
       ],
```

that gets it from command line when executing packer

This is the error I get :

> error(s) decoding:
>
> 'launch_block_device_mappings[0].volume_size' expected type 'int64', got unconvertible type '[]interface {}'

Is it impossible or what am I doing wrong ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. Packers templates are logicless. The standard way of achieving the what you want is to use `-var-file` where each vars file represents a role, e.g.

```
packer build -var-file=role-A.json template.json
```

In more complex cases we recommend that you preprocess your template and other files and wrap packer in some build script like `make`.